# Auth0-How to use with Flutter

Tags: flutter, auth0, flutter-dependencies

I need use **Auth0** with **Flutter** but there is no such SDK in Auth0 site.

**Auth0** works to create such **SDK** for Flutter.

Did anyone use Auth0 with Flutter or what can you advise?

Comment: Did you check this: [Flutter and Auth0](https://community.auth0.com/t/flutter-and-auth0/9676/7).

Comment: Yes, I did. Maybe will be another solutions too?

Comment: Did you try: https://github.com/WillyShakes/MasterLogin ?

Answer (score 1):

### Its very simple to get started with flutter auth0

Have a class for auth0 and call this at the places you need them. But also be sure to set the constants `AUTH0_DOMAIN`, `AUTH0_CLIENT_ID`, `AUTH0_REDIRECT_URI`, `AUTH0_ISSUER`

```
class Auth0 {

  final FlutterAppAuth appAuth = FlutterAppAuth();

  Map<String, Object> parseIdToken(String idToken) {
    final List<String> parts = idToken.split('.');
    assert(parts.length == 3);
    return jsonDecode(
        utf8.decode(base64Url.decode(base64Url.normalize(parts[1]))));
  }

  Future<Map<String, Object>> getUserDetails(String accessToken) async {
    const String url = 'https://$AUTH0_DOMAIN/userinfo';
    final http.Response response = await http.get(
      url,
      headers: <String, String>{'Authorization': 'Bearer $accessToken'},
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return jsonDecode(response.body);
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to get user details');
    }
  }

  Future<void> loginAction() async {
      isBusy = true;
      errorMessage = 'Error! - ';

    try {
      final AuthorizationTokenResponse result =
          await appAuth.authorizeAndExchangeCode(
        AuthorizationTokenRequest(
          AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
          AUTH0_REDIRECT_URI,
          issuer: 'https://$AUTH0_DOMAIN',
          scopes: <String>['openid', 'email', 'profile', 'offline_access'],
          promptValues: ['login']
        ),
      );

      final Map<String, Object> idToken = parseIdToken(result.idToken);
      final Map<String, Object> profile =
          await getUserDetails(result.accessToken);


        isBusy = false;
        name = idToken['name'];
        email = profile['email'];
        picture = profile['picture'];


    } on Exception catch (e, s) {
      print('login error: $e - stack: $s');

        isBusy = false;
        errorMessage = e.toString();
    }
  }
```

Instead of using a boolean for checking isLoggedIn try saving the token in the localstorage and that will set the state as is.

Answer (score 0):

There's an auth0 [package for flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_auth0) to use Auth0 API provides login, logout and access APIs for authentication in your App. However, you need to make changes inside `android` and `ios` files in your flutter project. You need to configure your callbacks and application settings for that, The author has their [example on github](https://github.com/devdennysegura/flutter-auth0/tree/master/example) that you should check out.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to follow the blog post provided by the Auth0 team -
[Get Started with Flutter Authentication](https://auth0.com/blog/get-started-with-flutter-authentication/)

Answer (score 0):

For Flutter Web App, I am making a wrapper around Auth0 JS SPA SDK.

GitHub: https://github.com/anthonychwong/auth0-flutter-web

Pub.dev: https://pub.dev/packages/auth0_flutter_web

```dart
import 'package:auth0_flutter_web/auth0_flutter_web.dart';

Auth0 auth0 = await createAuth0Client(
  Auth0CreateOptions(
    domain: '-- domain of the universal login page --',
    client_id: '-- id of your app --',
  )
);

String token = await auth0.getTokenWithPopup();
```

It is in very early stage and PRs are welcome.